# How can I get post back response using webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

Currently I am working on payment integration for native android app after send the request it have given me post back url with some attributes as success/fail response. I can't understand that how can I get those post back url attributes values using `WebView` . If any one know,
Please suggest me some idea for that.

Comment: try, startActivityForResult() method to get the response back of your Intent.

Comment: 1) do some google about `startActivityForResult()` usage 2) When you ask question, please use proper case, like 'I' instead of 'i'.